# Is complex analysis same difficulty as vector analysis/multivariable calculus?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, soft-question, vector-analysis

In vector calculus, you need some geometric intuition and find some integrals. I scanned a book on complex analysis and realized that they're aren't many pictures as we see in a multivariable textbook and there is always some substitution of variables going on when computing some integral. Is learning complex analysis in terms of computing integrals and derivatives just as easy as learning computational calculus? Why don't complex analysis books have as many pictures as calculus books do?

Because they're are less pictures in complex analysis books and tons of substitutions I can't understand, I'm guessing complex analysis isn't as easy as calculus.

Comment: Complex analysis is more like calculus (or real analysis) than like vector analysis. It's more than computing integrals and derivatives (but so is calculus). It's more advanced than calculus, but shouldn't be harder if you're properly prepared for it.

Comment: This book is for you https://www.amazon.it/Visual-Complex-Analysis-Tristan-Needham/dp/0198534469

Comment: Actually I have seen many more pictures in complex analysis than calculus. Anyway, I don't get how pictures should indicate the difficulty/easiness of something.

Comment: As most things in life, how hard it is depends on what level you do it on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are beautiful subjects and both are challenging...
Complex analysis is in some sense easier than vector calculus, because of various nice simplifications that occur as a result of the stronger differentiability condition...  but don't be mistaken, it's still plenty hard (unless your name is Cauchy or Riemann)...  also, complex. analysis can be seen as leading to several complex variables,  a very difficult subject...

Also, it's not always easy to draw pictures of complex funcions $w=f(z)$, as they are in a sense functions from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$...